# Discretionary equation breaking at a particular symbol

Tags: equations, line-breaking, breqn

I have long equations that I want LaTeX to break automatically. After some extensive searching I have been unable to work out how to achieve this effect. I have `breqn` in my package list, however it doesn't break the equations I have in the `equation` environment or math mode (or caption mode). For example it doesn't break:

```
A[A, k_a](M(\Box_0)) | I[k_a, d_k] | R(K[K, d_k, x]) \rightarrowtriangle A[A,k_a](M(\Box_0 | T[k_t])) | I[k_a,d_k] | I[k_t, d_k] | R(K[K,d_k,x])
```

I think this means I want to add `\mathpunct` for the `\rightarrowtriangle` and `|` symbols and only allow breaking of depth one. However I can't actually make this happen. I can't work out how to use the `\mathpunct` command or find what the symbol numbers of `\rightarrowtriangle` or `|` are.

Edit:

A minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}
\begin{dmath}
  A[A, k_a](M(\Box_0)) | I[k_a, d_k] | R(K[K, d_k, x]) \rightarrowtriangle A[A,k_a](M(\Box_0 | T[k_t])) | I[k_a,d_k] | I[k_t, d_k] | R(K[K,d_k,x])
\end{dmath}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Also, it would be helpful to mention that your code snippet requires the `stmaryrd` package.

Comment: You have to use the environments provided by `breqn` (see the manual) to get automatic line breaking, it doesn't change the behaviour of existing environments such as `equation`. Please add a minimal example, as suggested by Kevin.

Comment: Hi @KevinC , I've added the MWE, but TBH there really isn't anything in it bar what I put.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `\rightarrowtriangle` in such a way it's understood by `breqn`; then add a level of bracing and tell `breqn` to break only at level 0. I used `\mid`, perhaps you prefer `\vert` for the vertical bar.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_gset:cpx{mg@stmry}{\hexnumber@\symstmry}%
\DeclareFlexSymbol{\rightarrowtriangle}{Rel}{stmry}{5F}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{dmath}[breakdepth=0]
  \left.
  A[A, k_a](M(\Box_0)) \mid I[k_a, d_k] \mid R(K[K, d_k, x])
  \right.
  \rightarrowtriangle
  \left.
  A[A,k_a](M(\Box_0 \mid T[k_t])) \mid I[k_a,d_k] \mid I[k_t, d_k] \mid R(K[K,d_k,x])
  \right.
\end{dmath}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Actually there should be a `stmaryrd.sym` file for turning the definitions of `stmaryrd.sty` into something good for `breqn`. There isn't, at the moment.

---

Such an example confirm my opinion that it's a bad idea trying to automatize line breaks in equations.

The `breqn` package doesn't like `|`; one should use `\vert`, `\lvert`, `\rvert` or `\mid`, depending on the mathematical meaning of the bar. In this case one should use `\mid`; well, if one does it and makes the proper definition for `\rightarrowtriangle`, the result is as follows:

[image]

This is clearly unacceptable. If one uses `\vert`, no break can be taken. This works "automatically":

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_gset:cpx{mg@stmry}{\hexnumber@\symstmry}%
\DeclareFlexSymbol{\rightarrowtriangle}{Rel}{stmry}{5F}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

% breqn doesn't like |
\newcommand{\OR}{\hiderel{\mid}}


\begin{document}
\begin{dmath}
  A[A, k_a](M(\Box_0)) \OR I[k_a, d_k] \OR R(K[K, d_k, x])
  \rightarrowtriangle
  A[A,k_a](M(\Box_0 \OR T[k_t])) \OR I[k_a,d_k] \OR I[k_t, d_k] \OR R(K[K,d_k,x])
\end{dmath}
\end{document}
```

and produces

[image]

I'm asking myself where's the advantage over writing

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
& A[A, k_a](M(\Box_0)) \mid I[k_a, d_k] \mid R(K[K, d_k, x]) \\
& \quad {} \rightarrowtriangle
  A[A,k_a](M(\Box_0 \mid T[k_t])) \mid I[k_a,d_k] \mid I[k_t, d_k] \mid R(K[K,d_k,x])
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

that produces essentially the same result.

Comment: The value of automating it is that I have close to 40 pages of these for my dissertation. I can't go through all of them and add hundreds of \penalty0 things at every point. Especially as some of these occur in captions and thus would require substantial fiddling to get right.

Comment: @jhoyla I can understand; but if this "automation" doesn't work, it's worse than doing it manually. In my book I have 300+ pages with many long displayed equations involving big matrices: yes, I split them manually.

Comment: Is there really no way to have it split at a sensible place, and only split to an appropriate depth? Also I can't make your example work, I get an `undefined control sequence` on `cs`. What package am I missing? (I tried latex3 but I already have that.)

Comment: @jhoyla Try the new version. If you get undefined control sequence messages, then you have an outdated TeX distribution, probably.

Comment: You were right, my TeX distribution was from 2009, upgrading fixed it. Can I make just the `\rightarrowtriangle` break automatically without `\penalty0`

Comment: @jhoyla `\newcommand{\breakrightarrowtriangle}{\rightarrowtriangle\penalty0 }` or the other way around, depending where you want the break.

Comment: But that only works in breqn environments right?

Comment: @jhoyla In other environments the `\penalty` does nothing; but it's better to use `\rightarrowtriangle` in in-line formulas.